# How to embed "AVEVA (OSI Soft) - Pi Vision" displays

Tags: authentication, curl, ntlm-authentication, osisoft

I am working on a website in which I want to integrate AVEVA (OSI Soft) Pi Vision. Main requirement is to embed the Pi Vision displays in the new website.

I have a user, by which I am able to login on the portal and can view the `folders` and their `displays`.

I am following this API documentation which can list folders and the displays: https://docs.aveva.com/bundle/pi-vision-api-reference/page/overview.html

I gave permissions to the user mentioned in the above document: `Most PI Vision Display API endpoints require an authenticated user to be passed with the request. The user should belong to the PI Vision Utility Users or PI Vision Admins group on the target PI Vision server.`

But when I tried to run the following command in Postman:

```
curl --ntlm --negotiate -u USERNAME:PASSWORD --location --request GET 'https://piegp.******.com/PIVision/Utility/api/v1/folders' --header 'X-Requested-With: cURL' --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

It is not working and giving following reponse:
[image]

I never used `NTLM` authentication prior. Am I missing something in `NTLM` or there are some configuration related things which I am missing. Or if there are any other way to embed the Pi Vision display, please help me to find out.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Is NTLM enabled as a valid authentication method in the IIS settings for the PI Vision site? Usually it's recommended to configure the application to use Kerberos delegation, so it could be that you're *attempting* NTLM but the user is being pushed through a different authentication method. Start by making the security as loose as possible until it works, then work backwards by tightening until you figure out what was wrong. Whatever you do, keep track of whatever you're changing security wise and don't leave it poorly secured!